# VB Excel/How to select range until last row with data in entire range

Tags: excel, vba, range, selection

I have a table which is dynamic, amount of rows is always changing.

I'm looking for the code which would allow me to `Select` range within the table until last entry in the rows of whole range. Most formulas would select until last entry in the first column, but it can not be filled up.

[MARKED BY RED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2hak.png)
Thnaks a lot

Comment: Thanks,  Unfortunately trick select column H all the way down through entire worksheet. Idea was to select range marked by red. in the origin screenshot

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' replace Sheet1 with ur sheet name
Dim lr as Long: lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("H23:H" & lr).Select
```

> However, If I were you, [I'd steer clear from
>   `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba),
>   there are other much more effective means of achieving the same
>   result.